# Failed port-forward for my diy application in Openshift

Tags: java, sockets, binding, openshift, portforwarding

I have a java application with a server socket, but i don't know how to connect with another java web application in openshift. Looking in forums i saw i had to do port-forward to see wich ports i had to use in the connection between the web application(client) and the java  application(server). But i have this error:

http://postimg.org/image/gjrrs80lp/

I did ssh -N 536(..) too, but it didn't work. I'm full blocked, i've never worked with sockets and ports and i'm blocked.
Thanks for the help guys ;)

Answer (score 0):

You might do better to read up on sockets and ports then.  Can you give a specific error that you are getting?  If you are trying to use a non-supported port, then it will be blocked.  If you want to do port forwarding between gears then you need to make sure you have a public/private key setup on your gears for that purpose and added to your account.

Comment: Can you provide more information about which ports are supported and port forwarding on openshift?